# Network graph plot based on distance in Networkx Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx, directed-graph

I have data which I want to plot on the graph. The data looks like this:

```
SourceID| DestinationID| Distance
  1     |       5      |   20.9
  1     |       9      |   12.2
  1     |       15     |   22.6
........
  9     |       1      |   12.2
```

So from the last row you can see that it is multi directed graph. Currently, I am using the following code to plot the graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv', encoding='latin-1')

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

source = df['SourceId'].tolist()
destination = df['DestinationId'].tolist()

for j in range (len(source)):
    G.add_edge(source[j], destination[j])

nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G),node_size=300, node_color='green')
plt.show()
```

But I want to do things:
1. Draw this multi directed graph like Random Geometric Graph
2. Secondly the nodes adjust themselves on the basis of distances.

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can try using:

`nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G),node_size=300, node_color='green', prog='neato')`